# Python - slice only the value(array) in dictionary pair - is there a better way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, slice

I have a dictionary variable that contains a key and its corresponding value in the form of an array.

Example -

```
dict3

'2020-05-24T10:44:28.448188':[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
'2020-05-24T10:44:28.511500':[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
'2020-05-24T10:44:28.574870':[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
'2020-05-24T10:44:28.976331':[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
'2020-05-24T10:44:29.043868':[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
```

Now I would like to slice the value part of the pair till index 3. 
from

```
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

to

```
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

I read that slicing the value part alone of the dictionary isn't possible. So I converted it to a list and did the slicing there.

```
st = [(k,v[:4]) for k, v in dict3.items()]
```

Then converted back to dict.

```
dict3 = dict(st)
```

Is this a good approach? I will have to extend this logic to a larger dataset with 110,000 rows.

Is there a better approach?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could use a dictionary comprehension instead of list comprehension and avoid the conversion to dict.

Comment: Aren't the "value parts" strings, not lists?

Comment: Are those `(datetime, str)` tuples supposed to represent your `dict3`'s key and value respectively?

Comment: @Chris thanks. I was trying that before. Should have made a mistake. Was getting type error. Now it works.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes they are string. Before the task at hand, I exported them from a csv file using `ast.literal_eval()`. `dict((rows[0],ast.literal_eval(rows[1])) for rows in reader)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dictionnary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) will condense this in one operation:

```
st = {key: value[:4] for key, value in dict3.items()}
```

I believe this should be fine for 110,000 row. It'll double the memory footprint until the old dict is garbage collected, but 110,000 is not that much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for that `dictionary comprehension` with `eval` as

```
dict3 = {k: str(eval(v)[:4]) for k, v in dict3.items()}
```

This code will transform each list string to list then it will slice the list until the 3 index and then return it back to a string. 
The `eval` use here to covert string list to list.